# How to create a Vuetify loading button using composition api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to make a simple Vuetify button with the loading function. Vuetify has the component premade. I am trying to convert the code they provide to be used with composition api.

I'm running into problems with `this`.

Here is what Vuetify provides:

```html
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-btn
      class="ma-2"
      :loading="loading"
      :disabled="loading"
      color="secondary"
      @click="loader = 'loading'"
    >
      Accept Terms
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        loader: null,
        loading: false,
      }
    },
    watch: {
      loader () {
        const l = this.loader
        this[l] = !this[l]

        setTimeout(() => (this[l] = false), 3000)

        this.loader = null
      },
    },
  }
</script>

<style>
  .custom-loader {
    animation: loader 1s infinite;
    display: flex;
  }
  @-moz-keyframes loader {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes loader {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  @-o-keyframes loader {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  @keyframes loader {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
</style>
```

So converting to composition API, this is where I'm at. My `watch` function is obviously very wrong. Not sure if this is even the right way of using this new `watch`. The other issue is how to handle the `this` when it is in this format:

```js
import { ref, watch } from '@vue/composition-api'

setup () {
  let loader = ref(null)
  let loading = ref(false)

  watch( () => {
    loader () {
      const l = loader.value
      this[l] = !this[l]

      setTimeout(() => (this[l] = false), 3000)

      loader.value = null
    }
  })

  return {
    loader,
    loading,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 3.x [`watch`](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#watch) method, the first argument should be the `ref` (or array of `ref`s) you want to observe; and the second argument is the handler/callback, which receives the new value and old value as its arguments (as seen for the callback in [2.x `$watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch)).

For example, to setup a logger of new `ref` values:

```js
watch(myRef, (newValue, oldValue) => console.log(newValue))

// or
watch(myRef, () => console.log(myRef.value))
```

Regarding `this`: Since `loader.value` refers to one of the other `ref`s, you could just create a lookup for the target `ref`s that would be used by the `watch` callback. In this example, there's only one `ref` (but more could be added later):

```js
let loading = ref(false)

const refs = {
  loading
}

watch(myRef, () => {
  console.log(refs['loading'].value)
})
```

Altogether, the translated code using the Composition API would look like this:

```js
import { ref, watch } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default {
  setup() {
    let loader = ref(null)
    let loading = ref(false)

    const refs = {
      loading
    }
    watch(loader, () => {
      const l = loader.value
      if (!l) return

      refs[l].value = !refs[l].value

      setTimeout(() => (refs[l].value = false), 3000)

      loader.value = null
    })

    return {
      loader,
      loading
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-newton-krs4h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FAcceptTermsButton.vue&theme=dark)